# MVC 1.0 installation problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, installation

I have Visual Studio 2008 Team System with Framework 3.5 and SP1. I downloaded MVC framework 1.0 from the following location http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=53289097-73ce-43bf-b6a6-35e00103cb4b&displaylang=en and installed it. But after installation there was no MVC project template added to Create new Website or Create new Project in visul studio. I could not find a way to create MVC project. Even though the installation completed successfully, MVC project could not be created. Help me to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have choose ".NET Framework 3.5" option on the "New Project" dialog box.
[image]